# how can i add an array of int to a soap call

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

i have a problem with my webservice, it's running fine, but i need to send a array in the request and dont know how to do that...
i read, that ksoap does not support arrays in a request

how can i trick the service and send an array of int?

this is my code, which is working very well with all types :)

```
SoapObject result = null;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);

request.addProperty("int",new int[] {8,345,34,86,1,});
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE aHT = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

the following is logcat output after failing ;)

```
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wstest/com.example.wstest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at com.example.wstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-20 10:25:53.156: E/AndroidRuntime(23865):    ... 11 more
```

hope you can help me!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;


List<Integer> companies =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
companies.add(65);
companies.add(66);
companies.add(67);

Request.addProperty("name", "test1");
SoapObject soapCompanies = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "companies");
for (Integer i : companies){
    soapCompanies.addProperty("int", i);
}
Request.addSoapObject(soapCompanies);
```